# Flink task Manager hangs

Tags: flink-streaming

Here is the programme

```java
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
    StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);

ParameterTool parameters = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
String ftpUri ;

env.readTextFile(ftpUri,"UTF-8")
    .map(mapFunction)
    .keyBy(tuple2 -> tuple2.f0)
    .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(2)))
    .reduce((tuple2, t1) -> {
                Collection newCol = new ArrayList<OpisRecord>();
                Collections.addAll(newCol,tuple2.f1.toArray());
                Collections.addAll(newCol,t1.f1.toArray());         
                return  new Tuple2(tuple2.f0,newCol);
            })
     .addSink(new SinktoDistributedCache());

env.execute();
```

Works fine with for record size : 10k to 40k. But hangs up for anything above 40k.
I have tried increasing number task managers and parallelism but no gain.

Any clues ?

Comment: Have you tried running it in streaming mode? I'm wondering if the problem is related to the batch execution mode.

Comment: Disabling batch mode , led to a slightly different observation. The job got cancelled in a bit. Mostly the same split where batch mode used to get  hang up.

2021-06-23 06:03:23,646 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Split Reader: Custom File Source -> Map (1/1)#0 (8084f3288e1b2ea1a4c7c71a3af62681) switched from RUNNING to CANCELING.
2021-06-23 06:03:23,646 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Triggering cancellation of task code Split Reader: Custom File Source ->

Comment: If you read from a local file rather than an FTP URI does that make any difference?

Comment: Yes. It does. I see the job reaching conclusion.
I see when i give local file the content is read without chunking whereas when I provide a ftp chunking comes into it.

**2021-06-23 14:07:16,478 INFO  org.apache.XXX.ContinuousFileMonitoringFunction [] - Forwarding split: [0] ftp://data-injest:12345@ftp-server:21/input/100000.csv mod@ 1623876180000 : 0 + 4096**
     VS
**2021-06-23 14:04:03,552 INFO  org.apache.XXX.ContinuousFileMonitoringFunction [] - Forwarding split: [0] file:/local-samples/100000.csv mod@ 1623876217000 : 0 + 1800000**

Comment: Is there a change/configuration that I can try out to fix the performance/unblock the data pipeline when I am reading ftp source.

Comment: I’m not sure what’s wrong. I suggest you ask on the user mailing list.